# Customization of MS Teams UI Microsoft bot frmework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, servicenow

I recently saw the update in ServiceNow Bot in MS Team. The Activity view is evenly displayed and justified properly.  How is this customization possible ?

[image: ServiceNow Bot]

[image: My Bot]

Thanks for the idea

Comment: They are using the Adaptive cards. Please look at [Adaptive Cards in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that they're sending an [Adaptive Card](https://adaptivecards.io/) instead of a regular text message, but just one that doesn't have anything other than plain text in. So although Adaptive Cards *can* have rich content, these just look like better formatted plain text.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, Hilton. I tried Adaptive cards as well. But the alignment did not go well. May be will see if someone else also share their views.

Comment: sure, let's see. As a crazy workaround, you could create a long transparent png, and try use that to "fix" the width of the card...It's probably not a great idea though, as it might negatively affect mobile clients

Comment: Hey Hilton, you rock :)